# PHP Making a variable increment based on another variable's value without having too much code?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

i'm trying to  increase a variable value depending on the other variable value for example:

i have a variable called $totalhousesleft...

i want to set a price depending on how many $totalhousesleft i have...

everytime the totalhousesleft is down by 10, i want to increase the variable $currentprice by 1.

the starting value of $totalhouses left is 8000 and every time it goes down by 10, i set the $currentprice +1... the starting value of current price is 9...

something like:

```
If ($totalhousesleft >= 8000) {$currentprice = 9;  $sellingprice = 8;}
If ($totalhousesleft >= 7990) {$currentprice = 10;  $sellingprice = 9;}
If ($totalhousesleft >= 7980) {$currentprice = 11;  $sellingprice = 10;}
If ($totalhousesleft >= 7970) {$currentprice = 12;  $sellingprice = 11;}
```

ALL THE WAY DOWN UNTIL HOUSES LEFT IS 1. If someone can please show me a loop or a shorter code i would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` or `while` loop could be used for this. I'd use `for`:

```
$iteration = 0;
for($x = 8000; $x > 0; $x = $x - 10){  
    if(empty($iteration)) {
        $iteration = $x/1000;
    }
    if ($totalhousesleft >= $x) { 
        $currentprice = $iteration;
        $sellingprice = $currentprice + 1;
        break;
    }
    $iteration++;
}
if(empty($currentprice)){
    $currentprice =  $iteration;
    $sellingprice = $currentprice + 1;
}
```

This iterates over until a match is found then breaks out of the looping. The prices are based on the iteration it is in.

Demo link: https://3v4l.org/Mm432 (updated for edge cases 0-9)

Comment: Thank you but for some reason it's not working... it does work but i made $totalhousesleft go down 10 and the $currentprice did not change...

Answer (score 1):

[@elias-soares answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610716/2743458) is close, but is missing [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)...and an explanation.

```
foreach ( [8000, 7995, 7990, 7985, 7980, 7975, 7970, 7965] as $totalhousesleft ) {
    $currentprice = 9 + ((ceil(800 - ((min(8000, $totalhousesleft)) / 10))) * 1);
    $sellingprice = $currentprice - 1;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/68196

---

Let's break down how to get `$currentprice`:

```
//$currentprice = ceil(9 + (800 - (min(8000, $totalhousesleft) / 10)));

// get the lesser of 8000, or $totalhousesleft
// in other words, 8000 is the maximum number to calculate
$totalhousesleft = min(8000, $totalhousesleft);

// divide total houses left into number of tenth units
$tenth = $totalhousesleft / 10;

// since the price increases when the number of tenth units decreases,
// the unit factor is the difference between the max possible tenths 
// and tenths of the current total houses left
$tenthunit = 800 - $tenth;

// tenth unit is fractional for values not evenly divisible by 10,
// so round up
$tenthroundup = ceil($tenthunit);

// multiply the number of tenth units with the price per unit
$pricepertenth = $tenthroundup * 1; // 1 currency per tenth unit

// add the price per tenth cost to the base cost (9 currency)
$currentprice = 9 + $pricepertenth;
```

---

**Bonus**: this can be implemented in a function:

```
function getPrices ($totalhousesleft, $baseprice = 9, $discount = 1, $priceperunit = 1, $maxtotal = 8000, $units = 10) {
    $currentprice = $baseprice + ((ceil(($maxtotal / $units) - ((min($maxtotal, $totalhousesleft)) / $units))) * $priceperunit);
    return [$currentprice, $currentprice - $discount];
}

foreach ( [8000, 7995, 7990, 7985, 7980, 7975, 7970, 7965] as $totalhousesleft ) {
    list($currentprice, $sellingprice) = getPrices($totalhousesleft);
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/2672b

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.

```
$currentprice = 9 + (800 - (min(8000,$totalhousesleft)/10));
$sellingprice = $currentprice - 1;
```